# PHPUnit mock interface and class at the same time

Tags: php, unit-testing, tdd, phpunit

I have some code that looks like this:

```
public function foo(Bar $bar) {
    if ($bar instanceof Iterator) {
        //...
    }
}
```

To test this I'm using:

```
$this->getMock('Bar');
```

However, because my code is looking for an instance of Bar that implements Iterator it essentially has two types. By calling getMock('Bar') or getMock('Iterator') the code is untestable.

How can I make a mock implement an interface? This must be possible, surely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To mock something `PHPUnit` will create a **subclass** of the class you tell it to mock.

If `Bar` implements Iterator your `BarMock` will also implement Iterator.

### Sample.php

```
<?php

interface myInterface {

    public function myInterfaceMethod();

}

class Bar implements myInterface {

    public function myInterfaceMethod() {
    }

}

class TestMe {

    public function iNeedABar(Bar $bar) {
        if ($bar instanceOf myInterface) {
            echo "Works";
        }
    }
}

class TestMeTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    public function testBar() {
        $class = new TestMe();
        $bar = $this->getMock('Bar');
        $class->iNeedABar($bar);
    }

}
```

---

### Outputs:

```
phpunit Sample.php 
PHPUnit 3.7.8 by Sebastian Bergmann.

.Works

Time: 0 seconds, Memory: 5.25Mb

OK (1 test, 0 assertions)
```

Comment: In my real world problem, Bar is an abstract class that's being type hinted. It may then implements one of several interfaces to provide some optional functionality... I really need to mock that. I guess I'll have to define a class that extends the abstract class and implements the interface and mock that. Seems a long way around though.

Comment: @TomB Yes in that case you have to add a `class MyTestHelperThing implements Foo {}` in the test case and `$this->getMock('MyTestHelperThing');`. I'm not aware of any PHPUnit api for this.

Comment: Thanks, it seemed that way, but I had expected a method of defining that in PHPUnit itself.

Answer (score -1):

I think that you can mock the class using the Fully Qualified Name of the interface. Then, the mocked class implements the interface that you need.